# Checking multiple params in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra, parameters

These `params` come out of html inputs in erb templates (this code is in the main `application.rb`), and I am checking if they are filled before I add them to `n.requestusers`, which will become part of a database entry. It works, but it feels more like a bash script the way it is now. What would be the best way to write something like this?

**a route in the main .rb**

```
if params[:user2].empty? && params[:user3].empty? && params[:user4].empty? && params[:user5].empty?
  n.requestusers = params[:user1]
elsif params[:user3].empty? && params[:user4].empty? && params[:user5].empty?
  n.requestusers = params[:user1], params[:user2]
elsif params[:user4].empty? && params[:user5].empty?
  n.requestusers = params[:user1], params[:user2], params[:user3]
elsif params[:user5].empty?
  n.requestusers = params[:user1], params[:user2], params[:user3], params[:user4]
else
  n.requestusers = params[:user1], params[:user2], params[:user3], params[:user4], params[:user5]
end
```

Comment: Would you like to share your view? There might be a better way to do this than by sending a bunch of params[:userX]. Maybe a params[:users] ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of having all of those conditional statements might you be interested in something like:

```
n.requestusers = params.select { |key, val| not val.empty? }.values
```

Or a cleaner way as suggested by @theTinMan:

```
n.requestusers = params.reject { |key, val| val.empty? }.values
```

[select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) lets you take all of the none empty parameter values and returns them.  [values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-values) lets you grab those values as an array.

I am not experienced with web frameworks, so my suggestion is a bit of a shot in the dark.

Comment: +1 Two things to make it more Ruby-like. In general, instead of `not`, use `!`. For this code, instead of `select`, use `reject { |k, v| v.empty? }` because `not` or `!` makes us flip the logic in our heads. Switching to `reject` relies on the the success of the `empty?` test.

Comment: @theTinMan I agree with you.  I completely overlooked reject.  That is much more intuitive.

Comment: I notice those things because I don't like my head hurting. :-)

Comment: Yes! This is just the kind of thing I was looking for! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't tested, because there are no sample values to test against, but, after some refactoring I have:

```
if [:user2, :user3, :user4, :user5].all?{ |s| params[s].empty? }
  n.requestusers = params[:user1]
elsif [:user3, :user4, :user5].all? { |s| params[s].empty? }
  n.requestusers = [:user1, :user2].map{ |s| params[s] }
elsif [:user4, :user5].all? { |s| params[s].empty? }
  n.requestusers = [:user1, :user2, :user3].map{ |s| params[s] }
elsif params[:user5].empty?
  n.requestusers = [:user1, :user2, :user3, :user4].map{ |s| params[s] }
else
  n.requestusers = [:user1, :user2, :user3, :user4, :user5].map{ |s| params[s] }
end
```

Looking at that further, this seems sensible:

```
USER_LIST = [:user1, :user2, :user3, :user4, :user5]
USER_LIST.size.times do |i|
  user_list = USER_LIST
  get_users = user_list.shift(1 + i)
  if user_list.all?{ |s| params[s].empty? }
    n.requestusers = params.values_at(get_users)
    break
  end
end
```

Like I said, that's not tested, but I'd work with something along those lines.

Adjust `USER_LIST` as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with Sinatra, but if you wanted to add elements to the array, you can just do (assuming `n.requestusers` has already been initialized):

```
n.requestusers << params[:user1] unless params[:user1].empty?
```

You can do that for each user parameter.

**Edit**: It would probably be better just to check if the param exists since if it isn't found, `nil` is returned -- calling `empty?` on `nil` throws a `NoMethodError`. It would probably better to do:

```
n.requestusers << params[:user1] unless params[:user1]
```

This would ensure that it adds the param if it exists.

Comment: In case you do not know, `unless` translates to `if not`.